# Unexpected end of MySQL... See log file ? (windows XP + EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9)

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I noticed lot of similar error but I don't find the solution.
I'm the only user of the PC and than the admin... so I don't think the problem is on permissions.
I work with Windows XP and downloaded the last version of easyphp (EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9). If you need more info, ask!

This is the log file:

```
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-05-14 22:52:28 ba4  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-05-14 22:52:28 592 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Binlog end
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-05-14 22:52:29 592 [Note] C:\PROGRA~1\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql\bin\eds-mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Please help çç

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of this error in your log:

`2014-05-14 22:52:28 ba4  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2`

Because MySQL was not able to create the tempfile, the InnoDB engine did not start up, so it aborts the startup.

Check your MySQL install dir permissions, typically /var/lib/mysql and that you do not have any full partitions, where your temp directories reside. Fix that issue, and you will have a working MySQL installation.